# Do we need to upload cordova_plugin.js to phonegap build server?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am very new to Phonegap. I am trying to build an application which require InApBrowser plugin.

I know we should not upload cordova.js to PhoneGap Build server but I am not sure if we need to upload cordova_plugin.js to build server. I am asking this question because when I download the .ipa package and install it in iPhone and debug the application it says

```
cordova_plugin.js not found.
```

I am using cordova 3.6.3.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <p>Hello, your application is ready!</p>

    <!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.Plugintest" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <name>Plugin_test</name>
  <description>
    A blank project.
  </description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
    Apache Cordova Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <vs:features>
    <vs:feature>org.apache.cordova.device@0.2.10</vs:feature>
    <vs:feature>org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser@0.5.0</vs:feature>
  </vs:features>
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

But still it is not working in iphone
Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not need to include *cordova_plugin.js* to PhoneGap Build. In case of InAppBrowser, what you need to do is to include

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" />
```

into your *config.xml*. After that PhoneGap Build will take care of injecting all the necessary JavaScript files for you. You don't either need to do something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova_plugin.js"></script>
```

this in your app since PGB will handle it for you. That is one of the major benefits of using PGB.

**Update**

Here is example *config.xml* from one of my projects

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.com" version="0.0.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <name>Plugin_test</name>
  <description>
    A blank project.
  </description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
    Apache Cordova Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>

  <!-- PhoneGap plugins for PhoneGap Build to attach to build -->
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" source="pgb" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.5.2" source="pgb" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.4" source="pgb" />

  <!-- Use the newest version of PhoneGap -->
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />

  <!-- Device permission is needed -->
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device"/>

  <!-- Splash icon is on same directory as this file -->
  <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
</widget>
```

I left only the details you might need there such as plugins (splash, device and InAppBrowser) and permissions you are using 
Also move the *config.xml* under *www* folder, if not there already

Comment: I have updated my question. @sanfor I have done the steps as suggested by you. still its is saying cordova_plugin.js not found.

Comment: First, you do not need the _cordova.js_ script tag either, PGB will inject it by itself. Second, you are still missing the _gap:plugin_ directive from your _config.xml_. In PGB you can see the included plugins in the tab *plugins*. If there isn't InAppBrowser, it won't be included.

Comment: Thanks @sanfor.Your are correct I am not able to see the included plugins in the tab plugins. Can your please provide sample config.xml file with inappbrowser plugin in it?Thank you in advannce

Comment: @Vikash: There is example config now in answer.

Comment: No, you do need to manually inject the plugins JavaScript file(s) on your *index.html* after installing the plugin with `cordova plugin add *`,