# Phonegap Upgrade from 3.5 to 4.1.2-0.22.10, but when i create the project the version in always 3.5

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

I write here because i have a big problem with phonegap version.
I have upgrade phonegap on my MacBook (Maverik 10.9.5) from **3.5** to **4.1.2-0.22.10**, but when i create a new project the version is always 3.5.

```
$ phonegap --version
4.1.2-0.22.10

$ cordova --version
4.1.2

$ node --version
v0.10.35
```

Some one can help me please to solve this problem? Tnx

Comment: How do you identify which version are you using of Cordova and how do you create the project?

Comment: I create project in 2 standard metod: 

**`$cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"`**

or

**`$phonegap create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"`**

xml file show always versiom **3.5** but i have upgrade all to **4.1.2-0.22.10**. i dont know why in the xml version i have the prev version.

Comment: **<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the problem isn't that your Cordova wouldn't be the newest one. Instead the base for the project is copied from GitHub project called [PhoneGap Start](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start) which isn't yet updated to newer versions. On the plugin's documentation it tells

> This repository is automatically downloaded by phonegap-cli when you create a new application.

The newest version there is 3.5.0 currently, as can be seen from the [*config.xml*](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml) there.

Comment: ok but, when i go to build application on build.phonegap.com, the system tell me that the version of phonegap it's obsolete. so, i have to change the version in xml file? i have to change manually the version from 3.5.0 in 4.1.2-0.22.10 like this **<preference name="phonegap-version" value="4.1.2-0.22" />**???

Comment: If you use PhoneGap Build, the maximum version is [3.6.3](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/09/30/phonegap-3_6_3-now-on-build/) on the moment. And yes, just alter the version manually. The example project needs to be anyway updated to match PGB.

Comment: can tell me please how to upgrade the example project correctly at 3.6.3? or how to build a project without the phonegap-start, if it possible? (tnx for you replyes. at moment i cant vote you up because i dont have 15 point of reputation. when i take the correct amount for rate you, i come back here for vote you. tnx)

Comment: @methdev: please see an example of my own PGB [_config.xml_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27842152/1744702) that is using all the latest features available on PGB. In addition to upvoting, please also remember to approve the answer if you feel it helped you to solve your problem.